# Overlay on top of ImageView

Tags: android-layout, android-imageview

I have an ImageView which I load with a bitmap, scaleType is set to  center_crop. I want an overlay on top of it, a RelativeLayout would do.

My problem is that my overlay never ends up being the same size as my ImageView and overlay children must maintain positions over the imageView.

The children of the overlay will most likely be a bunch of ImageButtons, so to be able to tap on specific points on the map.

I have both ImageView and RelativeLayout with a FrameLayout as parent. I request the image content to be downloaded via HTTP, when it is received, I load the ImageView and then I set the overlay size using `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`, setting the size of the ImageView (via getWidth and getHeight) but the size is always off.

Also, if the overlay is resized to match the imageView's size, it should also apply scaling to its children, otherwise resizing won't do much.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What overlay is it? why not make a custom view and draw the bitmap and overlay all at once?

Comment: Probably should have explained better, the idea is for the overlay to contain ImageButtons, so the user can tap on specific parts of the image, which will contain a map. The ImageButtons will also change the  image depending on certain states of these locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on the order the views are inflated/created you might try to invalidate the complete view to enforce that the correct width&height attributes are known when inflaiting the elements

Comment: Thank you, explained further, I also need to perform some sort of scaling, otherwise the overlay's children positions are not maintained on top of the image.